# C++ custom class mapping retrieving value from map adds new index

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an a* algorithm to find the shortest path from source node to target node. In the last part of the function I want to loop over the visited nodes and add the shortest path to the `std::vector<map::map_node*> path`. However, this line of code seems to add an index to `previous` instead of retrieving the value: `map::map_node* current_node = previous[&target_node];`.

How can I retrieve the value of the map by using the target node as key without it adding a random index in the `previous` map, to get a path from the source to the target node?

I'm using the following framework for my application: https://nullptr.club/libkmint/annotated.html

Source code:

```
void helper::shortest_path_to_target(map::map_node &source_node, map::map_node &target_node)
{
    std::vector<map::map_node*> visited;
    std::vector<map::map_node*> queue;
    std::map<map::map_node*, map::map_node*> previous;
    std::map<map::map_node*, float> cost;
    std::map<map::map_node*, float> heuristic_cost;

    queue.push_back(&source_node);
    cost[&source_node] = 0;
    heuristic_cost[&source_node] = heuristic(source_node, target_node);

    while (queue.size() > 0) {
        map::map_node* shortest_path_node = shortest_distance(cost, heuristic_cost, queue);

        for (int i = 0; i < shortest_path_node->num_edges(); i++) {
            map::map_edge &edge = (*shortest_path_node)[i];
            map::map_node *node_to = &edge.to();

            if (std::find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), node_to) == visited.end()
                && std::find(queue.begin(), queue.end(), node_to) == queue.end()) {
                queue.push_back(node_to);

            }

            if (cost.find(node_to) == cost.end() || cost[node_to] > cost[shortest_path_node] + edge.weight())
            {
                cost[node_to] = cost[shortest_path_node] + edge.weight();
                heuristic_cost[node_to] = heuristic(*shortest_path_node, target_node);
                previous[node_to] = shortest_path_node;
            }

            if (node_to == &target_node)
            {
                cost[node_to] = cost[shortest_path_node] + edge.weight();
                heuristic_cost[node_to] = heuristic(*shortest_path_node, target_node);
                previous[node_to] = shortest_path_node;
                break;
            }
        }
        queue.erase(queue.begin());
        visited.push_back(shortest_path_node);
    }

    // shortest path to target_node
    map::map_node* current_node = previous[&target_node];
    path.clear();
    while (current_node != &source_node) {
        path.insert(path.begin(), current_node);
        current_node = previous[current_node];
    }
}

map::map_node* helper::shortest_distance(std::map<map::map_node*, float>& cost, std::map<map::map_node*, float>& heuristic_cost, std::vector<map::map_node*>& queue)
{
    map::map_node *closest_to_target_node = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
        if (closest_to_target_node == nullptr || cost[queue[i]] + heuristic_cost[queue[i]] < cost[closest_to_target_node] + heuristic_cost[closest_to_target_node]) {
            closest_to_target_node = queue[i];
        }
    }
    return closest_to_target_node;
}

// Manhattan distance heuristic is mostly used in standard grid where you can only move in 4 directions
float helper::heuristic(const map::map_node &source_node, const map::map_node &target_node)
{
    // Lowest cost between adjacent squares
    int D = 1;
    return std::abs(source_node.location().x() - target_node.location().x()) + std::abs(source_node.location().y() - target_node.location().y());
}
```

Comment: `previous[&target_node];` only inserts a new element in the map if the key `&target_node` hasn't been inserted before. So if it adds a new element to the map, then that means that `&target_node` has not been inserted beforehand. So your algorithm is wrong somewhere and didn't insert the key. I suggest you step through it in a debugger with a simple test case to see where it goes wrong.